# How to get DS annotation v1.3.0 in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, annotations, osgi, equinox

I am developing an OSGI application with Eclipse based on Equinox. Now I would like to use DS annotation v1.3.0 mainly for field's injection which are not available in v1.2.0. But I don't know how to set up my build to get the correct version of "org.osgi.service.component.annotations" (the only available is v1.2.0) ?

Comment: Why not use Bndtools?

Comment: I didn't know this tool until yesterday, my tool chain is composed of maven, tycho, pde. I spend a lot of time every day to configure this one, may be it's time to simplify it with bndtools! Do you know if maven is still relevant with bndtools? Because major of my colleagues works with standard jars and maven so I need a good argument to tell them that I deserted maven.

Comment: Bndtools is different than maven but you can use the JARs from Maven central and you release to Nexus/Artifactory. We're about to release a special Maven repository in bnd that is using a standard Maven POM as its specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Declarative Services Specification 1.3 is not usable with Eclipse Equinox on the date of June 21, 2016 ([see Dirk Fauth's article](http://blog.vogella.com/2016/06/21/getting-started-with-osgi-declarative-services/)).